# Can Windows remember & re-apply administrator/UAC permissions?

Tags: windows, uac

Is it possible to write and configure a Windows application that, once given UAC permission by the user to run as an Administrator, will remember that permission and give it to the program when it runs again later?

Such as for a device driver updater. Repeatedly asking the user for permission can be annoying.

Comment: You could create & start a service.

Comment: Windows only grants permissions to regular applications for a single run. The way around it is as @SLaks suggests.

Comment: I had considered the service method, but I have not finished looking into it as an alternative. Thank you for saying it is likely to work. If you write that as an answer, I will accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for UAC to have an *always remember this option*. This is an intentional design decision.

Especially in this case, where you are doing horribly dangerous things such as updating a device driver.

That code is something that **should** only be done by an administrator, behind a safety barrier.